# Conditional calculation based on values in other column

Tags: r

Suppose I have a `data.frame`, I wish to create a new column called `duration`, it is calculated only for records where `status = Active`, using `2016-12-10` as today's date, so that `duration = today - start_date`.

What's the best approach for this conditional calculation?

```
status <- c("Active", "Inactive", "Active")    
date <- c("2016-10-25", "2015-05-11", "2015-3-18")    
start_date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")    
data.frame(status, start_date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create the logical index in 'i' and assign (`:=`) the difference between 'today' and 'start_date' as the 'duration' column.  This will be efficient as it assigns in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[status == "Active", duration := today - start_date]
df1
#     status start_date duration
#1:   Active 2016-10-25  46 days
#2: Inactive 2015-05-11  NA days
#3:   Active 2015-03-18 633 days
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
i1 <- df1$status == "Active"
df1[i1, "duration"] <- today - df1$start_date[i1]
```

where

```
today <- as.Date("2016-12-10")
```

Answer (score 0):

using `dplyr`, you can try:

```
dft %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(duration = ifelse(status == "Active", (today - start_date), NA))
```

where `dft` is your initial dataframe.